# Sprite Sheet animation with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, animation, sprite, sprite-sheet

I can't seem to figure out how to make the animations work when moving the character, when I press a key down, the animation plays through the whole sprite sheet instead of one row, the animation also doesn't stop when I let off of the key. I want to be able to make the animation work in different rows, for example if I press the down arrow I want the first row to play only, and when I let go I want it to stop.

Please help me with this code to animate my character with the different rows when I press different keys, and be able to stop the animation when I let go of a key.

[image: My Image]
as you can see, the first row of the image is for when you press the down key, second row for left key, third row for right key, and fourth row for up key.

I am using a the Phaser javascript framework by Photon Storm.

**JavaScript, game.js:**

```
  var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { 
  preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

function preload() {

  game.stage.backgroundColor = '#ff6288';
  game.load.spritesheet('player','reddude.png', 64, 64);

}

var player;
var cursors;

function create() {

  game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 1920, 1920, 'background');

  game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1920);

  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

  player = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 
 'player');

  game.physics.p2.enable(player);

  player.animations.add('walk');
  player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 1);

  cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

  game.camera.follow(player);

}

function update() {

  player.body.setZeroVelocity();

  if (cursors.up.isDown)
  {
    player.animations.play('walk', 10, true);
    player.body.moveUp(100)
  }
  else if (cursors.down.isDown)
  {
    player.animations.play('walk', 10, true);
    player.body.moveDown(100);
  }

  if (cursors.left.isDown)
  {
    player.animations.play('walk', 10, true);
    player.body.velocity.x = -100;
  }
  else if (cursors.right.isDown)
  {
    player.animations.play('walk', 10, true);
    player.body.moveRight(100);
  }

}

function render() {

  game.debug.cameraInfo(game.camera, 32, 32);
  game.debug.spriteCoords(player, 32, 500);

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple Canvas Game</title>
    <style>
      html {
        background: black
      }
      canvas {
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="phaser.js"></script>
       <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to define multiple animations in `create()`. One for each direction.

https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.AnimationManager.html#add

```
player.animations.add('down',  [0,1,2,3]);
player.animations.add('left',  [4,5,6,7]);
player.animations.add('right', [8,9,10,11]);
player.animations.add('up',    [12,13,14,15]);
```

And then you need to play the particular animation for each direction in `update()`:

https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.AnimationManager.html#play

https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.AnimationManager.html#stop

```
if (cursors.up.isDown){
  player.animations.play('up', 10, false);
  player.body.moveUp(100);
} else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
  player.animations.play('down', 10, false);
  player.body.moveDown(100);
} else if (cursors.left.isDown) {
  player.animations.play('left', 10, false);
  player.body.velocity.x = -100;
} else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
  player.animations.play('right', 10, false);
  player.body.moveRight(100);
} else {
  player.animations.stop(null, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel stupid, I redid my code like this before you answered, but I forgot that the frame doesn't start with 1, but starts with 0 instead.